# I can't return the image of a record located in the storage folder

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to display an image of a record in the table using storage, the code I made is not returning the image, and when I put its path in the browser it is possible to see the image.

- Column to show image at table

```
<td> <img src="{{ url(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('local')->url($cli->image_client)) }}" class="w-16 h-auto"></td>
```

- Path from file

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/client/storage/app/avatars/yTYkibyZFb9oYaF4uPfgHTg25Pa599PYiVI7btMC.jpg
```

- `filsystems.php`

```
    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('avatars') => storage_path('app/avatars'),
    ],
```

- `dd($validations['image_client'])`

```
"avatars/yTYkibyZFb9oYaF4uPfgHTg25Pa599PYiVI7btMC.jpg" // app/Http/Controllers/ClientController.php:49
```

Comment: Did you link your storage folder to the public folder as described in the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: 'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('avatars') => storage_path('app/avatars'),
    ],

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link` after that?

Comment: If you look at the generated HTML, what is the value of `src`?

Answer (score 0):

To access the file in the `avatars` folder:

```php
<img src="{{public_path($cli->image_client)}}" class="w-16 h-auto">
```

Or, from the storage directory:

```php
<img src="{{storage_path("app/" . $cli->image_client)}}" class="w-16 h-auto">
```

Comment: ```<img src="{{storage_path("app/" . $cli->image_client)}}" class="w-16 h-auto">```don't working.

Comment: Value of ```src=""```return ```src="/opt/lampp/htdocs/client/storage/app/avatars/yTYkibyZFb9oYaF4uPfgHTg25Pa599PYiVI7btMC.jpg"```

Comment: what `storage_path("app/" . $cli->image_client)` returns?
Does it return this: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/client/storage/app/avatars/yTYkibyZFb9oYaF4uPfgHTg25Pa599PYiVI7btMC.jpg` ?

Comment: But in the column of the table the image is not shown.

Comment: if you have linked the storage path to the public, you can try this: `<img src="./storage/{{$cli->image_client}}">`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td> <img src="{{ asset($cli->image_client) }}" height=100 width=100></td>
```